# Waiting for process: crond in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shutdown

shutdown/reboot stuck saying Waiting for process: crond in ubuntu LTS 20.04 in hp elitebook g2 with[system_information****](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftHKX.png)

error  image attached here--> [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3cqe.jpg)

Comment: please edit your question, you have two times the same image with wrong description..

Comment: it has been resolved as i use bleachbit to just clean up the system and everything works fine.